# Why do some works [anime, manga, novels] have a trailing dot?

Tags: anime-history

Pure curiosity.

Why do some series carry a dot [.] at the end of their titles?
Is there a meaning to it or is it convention?

Ex: [Ore, Twintail ni Narimasu.](http://myanimelist.net/anime/24705/Ore_Twintails_ni_Narimasu.), [Kobato.](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5678/Kobato.)

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a period / full-stop. "Ore, Twintail ni Narimasu" is a full sentence in Japanese, so hey, why not toss a period on the end of that.

Comment: So its more like making sense of the title than just a simple styling or convention?

Comment: The second season of Oreimo ([Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii Wake ga Nai.](http://myanimelist.net/anime/13659/Ore_no_Imouto_ga_Konnani_Kawaii_Wake_ga_Nai.)) has it, and the first one doesn't. It's actually how they are differentiated in the title. There's no 2 or Season 2 or anything of the sort.

Comment: Correct, I remember that about the series. There never was a season season of the novel (no need for that, just make another volume) - but when it came to the anime something was needed to tell them apart. Any idea why studios are choosing to go this route instead of just adding a '2' like series before.

It could simply be a newer thing though, I have noticed this practice more with novels, but it looks like it is spreading.
Sort of like the really long title syndrome. (LOL)

Comment: I think it's likely a combination of both senshin and JNat's answers - given how many light novel titles are now full sentences, it makes a certain perverse sense to make them grammatically correct by putting a period at the end; at the same time, there's also a trend to identify sequels with punctuation marks (e.g. Working'!!) which is in itself an extension of the naming convention of adding a short word rather than numbering seasons (going back to, at the very least, Slayers Next and Try).

Comment: I think it's because the title is a sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The punctuation symbol  **。** is called a [句点](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Full_stop) (*kuten*). Although it often functions like the English period (a.k.a. full stop), it is **not identical**, and is [used as the punctuation mark for a question sentence far more often than the ? symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Question_mark) is (the question mark is called 疑問符 [*gimonfu*] or はてな [*hatena*]. [Historically, Japanese did not have the question mark](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%96%91%E5%95%8F%E7%AC%A6#.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E8.AA.9E), so although it exists in Japan now, it is not used in Japanese academic writing). In horizontal writing, the *kuten* is placed in the same position as a period would be in English: at the bottom right of the preceding character. In vertical writing, it is placed immediately below and to the right of the preceding character.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Full_stop) explains that

> Starting in the 1980s, advertising copy writers began incorporating full stops in titles and other advertising. In the 1990s, the group Morning Musume (モーニング娘。) began using a full stop in its name, starting a fad for this usage.

Other cases include

- バクマン。 (*Bakuman*) manga by  Ooba Tsugumi and Obata Takeshi
- いいひと。 (*Ii Hito*) manga by Takahashi Shin
- 野ブタ。をプロデュース (*Nobuta wo Produce*) live-action TV drama

As you can see, "Bakuman" is not a full sentence by itself, and "Nobuta. Wo Produce" intentionally slices a single phrase into two fragments by the placement of the *kuten* (Nobuta is the nickname of a main character that the protagonist decides to "produce," meaning to make-over *Pygmalion*-style.  Grammatically, you cannot make "Wo Produce" into its own sentence), so these are both examples of a *kuten* that should not be interpreted as a period for ending a sentence. The *kuten* can be utilized as a sentence ender, but it is often **used for style without any grammatical meaning**. Similarly, some series titles make use of other **Japanese typographic symbols** for style such as　[image], [＊](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_typographic_symbols#Other_special_marks), [☆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(glyph)#Five_points), [♪](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note), and [♯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_(music)) (for example, うたの☆プリンスさまっ♪ [*Uta no Prince-sama*] and おジャ魔女どれみ♯ [*Oja Majo DoReMi Sharp*] and the choice of a star to be read as the letter A in [ST☆RISH](http://utanoprincesama.wikia.com/wiki/ST%E2%98%86RISH), an idol group in the former).