# What is the real title of a piano song "Another Side 02 - Track 4"?

Tags: music, guilty-crown

Was wondering if anyone could find the name of the piano song "Another Side 02 - Track 4".

Answer (score 1):

"Another Side 02" is actually the album title, and with this information, it's quite trivial to find a site with the tracklist, such as [VGMDB](https://vgmdb.net/album/32069).

> - Album: GUILTY CROWN SOUNDTRACK ANOTHER SIDE 02
> - Composed by Hiroyuki Sawano
>
> Tracklist:
> Disc 1
>
> 1. pF-AdLibⅠ (Pianoforte-AdLib I)
> 2. gT→pF (Guitar→Pianoforte)
> 3. pF-AdLibⅡ  (Pianoforte-AdLib II)
> 4. **fUE+p@D+hArP→pF (Flute+Pad+Harp→Pianoforte)**
> 5. sT+hRN+tRB+tUba (Strings+Horns+Trombone+Tuba)
> 6. pF-AdLibⅢ (Pianoforte-AdLib III)
> 7. 1616 (Various)
> 8. gT→sYnTH (Guitar→Synth)
> 9. pF-AdLibⅣ (Pianoforte-AdLib IV)

(As for why the song title seems strange, [it's Sawano's quirk](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/confusion-about-the-naming-of-aldnoah-zeros-ost-opening-ending-song-titles))